# Ubuntu ACPI Error

Tags: boot, uefi

I tried to boot a pendrive with Ubuntu 20.04 and soon after an Ubuntu 21.04 using Ventoy (multiboot pendrive), I tested all the other versions of ubuntu and they will all give me the same error. My system's architecture is x64.

My current operating system is Windows 10, I made the BIOS settings correctly:
Secure boot disabled, Intel Trusted Platform Disabled, System Optimized defaults disabled, System support UEFI.

[image: acpi bios errors]

Comment: This sort of issue is usually seen when there are problems with the storage device (the SSD or HDD, not the USB stick). It can also happen if the initial OS is hibernating. Is Windows configured to use "Fast Boot"? If so, that needs to be disabled, otherwise the existing partition(s) on the storage medium will be marked as open, preventing Ubuntu (and most other OSes) from working with it.

Comment: Yes, fastboot is disabled.

Comment: Have you tried writing the ISO to media in the approved & QA-tested manner, ie. Ubuntu - https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
Mac - https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
windows - https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

Comment: If using the 3rd party `ventoy`, are you using a version that is capable or writing the ISOs you intend, as Ubuntu ISOs have changed how they boot in order to make them (a) boot the same on all architectures, and (b) make it boot faster on most boxes... this has caused changes so 3rd party tools that wrote older ISOs may no longer write more recent ISOs.  Ubuntu ISO writing tools have been QA-tested & work.

Comment: Dont work @guiverc